# Oracle Coherence fast empty complete cluster

Tags: oracle-coherence

I'm having problems with a cache cluster to empty all cache data stores.

This cluster has 89 cache stores and lasts more than 40 minutes to completely unload data.

I'm using this function:

```
public void deleteAll() {
    try {
        getCache().clear();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error unloading cache",getCache().getCacheName());
    }
}
```

getCache Method retrieves a NamedCache of CacheFactory.

```
public NamedCache getCache() {
    if (cache == null) {
        cache = com.tangosol.net.CacheFactory.getCache(this.idCacheFisica);
    }

    return cache;
}
```

Has anyone found any other way to do this faster?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Is the `eraseAll` method being called on each `CacheStore`?

Comment: Yes, the purpose of this method is leave cache cluster empty to reload new data.

Comment: So you're using a `CacheStore` but initializing the cache outside of the cluster?  If that's really what you want to do I'd look at the implementation of the `CacheStore`s - are they deleting rows a single key at a time or doing a bulk delete?

Comment: yes, the data update comes from an external event. 
And I can't find any reference to bulk deleting. 
But, It would be enough with a fast cache clearing method. Because, next they will load all data again.
Thank you in advance Nick.

Comment: Please add some sample code for one of the `CacheStore` implementations

Comment: added getCache source

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I meant.  Your question mentions 'cache stores'.  `CacheStore` is the interface you implement in order for read/write through to work.  Assuming this is what you mean by 'cache store', when you call `clear` Coherence will (I think) call the `eraseAll` method of the `CacheStore`, which if badly implemented could cause a performance issue.  What I want to see is you implementation of the `CacheStore` interface

Comment: Thank you for your comments.
I'm not implementing any other interface. 
I just call 
     `com.tangosol.net.CacheFactory.getCache("cacheName");`
and when I want to unload data then I call 
     `getCache().clear()`
probably it is calling eraseAll and thus I'm having bad performance.
How should I do a massive unload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's strange it would take so long, though to be honest, it's unusual to call `clear`.

You could try destroying the cache with [NamedCache.destroy](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18686_01/coh.37/e18683/com/tangosol/net/NamedCache.html#destroy__) or [CacheFactory.destroy(NamedCache)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18686_01/coh.37/e18683/com/tangosol/net/CacheFactory.html#destroyCache_com_tangosol_net_NamedCache_).

The only problem with this is that it invalidates any references that there might be to the cache, which would need to be re-obtained with another call the [CacheFactory.getCache](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18686_01/coh.37/e18683/com/tangosol/net/CacheFactory.html#getCache_java_lang_String_).

Answer (score 0):

Often, a "bulk operation" call like clear() will get transmitted all the way back to the backing maps as a bulk operation, but will at some point (somewhere inside the server code) become a iteration-based implementation, so that each entry being removed can be evaluated against any registered rules, triggers, event listeners, etc., and so that backups can be captured exactly. In other words, to guarantee "correctness" in a distributed environment, it slows down the operation and forces it to occur as some ordered sequence of sub-operations.

Some of the reasons why this would happen:

1. You've configured read-through, write-through and/or write-behind behavior for the cache;
2. You have near caches and/or continuous queries (which imply listeners);
3. You have indexes (which need to be updated as the data disappears);
4. etc.

I will ask for some suggestions on how to speed this up.

Update (14 July 2014) - Yes, it turns out that this is a known issue (i.e. that it could be optimized), but that to maintain both "correctness" and backwards compatibility, the optimizations (which would be significant changes) have been deferred, and the clear() is still done in an iterative manner on the back end.